# Why My Hair Strand Render Doesn't Reflect On The Water? [Internal Render]

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, hair

I'm trying to make a model of the pond terrain with hair particle as a grass, and I enabled the strand render setting... But when I render it, the hair particle (Grass) doesn't reflect on the water

Does anybody have a solution for this? Or is it a bug from Blender?

With Strand Render:

[image: With Strand Rendering]

Without Strand Render:

[image: Without Strand Render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More limitation than bug. The strand primitive in Blender Internal does not support raytracing, thus doesn't show up in reflections. If you need that, it's best to just not use the strand option, or use Cycles.

Comment: Hm.. what a dissapointment =w= thanks for answering my question anyway